# 1.5 volt RAM in a 1.35 RAM compatible laptop

Tags: laptop, memory

My laptop is asus rog 750jx, it was said that it compatible with 1.35v ram. But i installed a 1.5v ram onto the laptop. Will it be okay?

Comment: No; it won't the memory in question requires higher voltage the your motherboard can supply

Comment: When you say "a 1.5v ram", what *precisely* do you mean? Do you mean RAM that can tolerate 1.5V? Or do you mean RAM that requires 1.5V?